# PHP MD5 File Name

Tags: php, file, upload, md5

I have an upload script, and to fix the upload for several things, I want to md5 encrypt the files name. Here is the top of the php script I am using.

> `$target_dir = "file_dir/";
>   $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
>   $uploadOk = 1;
>   $imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);`

I attempted to use the md5() method like this

> `md5($target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]));`

which did not work. Just came back as an error.
If you guys need more code in this script to help me, please tell me in the comments and i'll make a dummy copy of my script. Thank's in advance :D

Comment: yes, please post more code - see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I figured out that the name of the file has something to do with "fileToUpload", thought that would be a helpfull tip

Comment: Here is all the code in one file > https://upload.blackvikingpro.com/upload.txt

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use basename on a path which doesn't exist: $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]. This is just the filename and not the path in the server.

You can just use this for unique filename:

```
md5($target_dir . '/' . $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"])
```

Clearly you will need to make sure that filename is always unique. If that's not an option then you could also use and this is much more likely to be unique:

```
md5($target_dir . '/' . $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"])
```

If you want to make sure that its always unique then this will work:

```
md5($target_dir . '/' . $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"] . time())
```

Several options. It just depends what you want to do with them.

Comment: I used the "md5($target_dir . '/' . $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"])" method. However, it didn't md5 encrypt the name. Just didn't do anything... Any other method for the "["name"]"?

Comment: can you do a var_dump of $_FILES? It sounds as if the file name is empty.

Comment: So, I attempted to use this... `$target_file = $target_dir . md5($_FILES["fileToUpload"]) . basename(["name"]);` which did the job. But it encrypted the file extension as well. Meaning that it didn't pass my security code, so the file failed to upload. I just want to encrypt the name, not the extension.

Comment: Can I do a `$target_dir = "target_dir/";
// $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
// $target_file = $target_dir . md5($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);

// Encrypt File Name...


$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

$target_file = md5($target_file).'.'.$imageFileType;`?

Answer (score 0):

Late answer but hope it helps you.
You are trying to encrypt the directory along with the file. This must be causing the error.

You should encrypt just the file and add the file extension:

```
$file_ext = strrchr($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"], '.');
$target_file = md5(basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"])).$file_ext;
```

And then pass it to move **move_uploaded_file**

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_dir.$target_file)
```